# C++ memcpy from double array to float array

Tags: c++, memcpy

Is is possible to memcpy from a double array to a float array safely?

Comment: Depends what you mean by safely.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Depends on what you want. The values certainly won't be preserved. If you need that, use `std::copy`.

```
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    double a[] = {1.618, 3.1416, 2.7, 0.707, 1.0};
    float b[5];
    std::copy(a, a + 5, b);
}
```

Comment: This does not work (for me on VS2017) since the compiler does not allow the implicit loss of precision from double to float via `std::copy`.
I had to use the `std::transform` function instead, using a lamda. This also clearer shows that an explicit loss-of-precision is actually taking place.

Comment: @AzP it sounds like you've chosen compiler options to make it reject valid code then. (Or there's a compiler bug)

Comment: @M.M well, implicit loss of precision is a bit dangerous - depending on what you are working with - and using a warning level of 4 will result in a compiler warning. Since I'm using 'treat warnings as errors' it won't compile. "Valid code" in this sense doesn't mean 'good code'.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that there is no guarantee that the compiler's binary representation of a `double` is the equivalent representation of a `float`.  In order to use `memcpy` for multi-byte types is that the underlying representation must be the same (same layout).  You can safely copy `float` to `float`, `int` to `int` and `double` to `double`.

You are destined for *undefined behavior* when the source type does not match the destination type, such as copying from `long` to `char` or `float` to `double`.  The `memcpy` function does not make any conversion or perform any promotions.  It just copies.

Answer (score 3):

Like many others have answered, using `memcpy` does not work since the two types are (generally) different in size. Please see more at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types, or more specifically:

> **Floating point types**
>
> **float** - single precision floating point type.
>   Usually IEEE-754 32 bit floating point type
>
> **double** - double precision floating point type. Usually IEEE-754 64 bit floating point type
>
> **long double** - extended precision floating point type. Does not necessarily map to types mandated by IEEE-754. Usually 80-bit x87 floating point type on x86 and x86-64 architectures.

Using `std::copy` will give you a compiler warning (at least for me on the VS2015/VS2017 compiler) since the compiler does not allow the implicit loss of precision from double to float via std::copy, without warning the developer about it. And if you have the `treat warnings as errors` flag set, you will get a compiler error.

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xutility(2316): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xutility(2335): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Copy_unchecked1<_InIt,_OutIt>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,std::_General_ptr_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _OutIt=float *,
1>            _InIt=double *
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xutility(2354): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt *std::_Copy_unchecked<_InIt,float*>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _OutIt=float *,
1>            _InIt=double *
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xutility(2364): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Copy_no_deprecate1<double*,_OutIt>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,std::random_access_iterator_tag,std::random_access_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _OutIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<float>>>,
1>            _InIt=double *
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xutility(2373): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Copy_no_deprecate<_InIt,_OutIt>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _OutIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<float>>>,
1>            _InIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<double>>>
1>        ]
1>test.cpp(153): note: see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::copy<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<double>>>,std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<float>>>>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _OutIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<float>>>,
1>            _InIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<double>>>
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xutility(2316): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
```

Instead, I recommend using use the `std::transform` function, combined with a lamda performing the specific cast. This also clearer shows that an explicit loss-of-precision is actually taking place.

```
std::vector<double> doubles = { 5.0, 10.0, 242.130, 42.0 };
std::vector<float> floats(doubles.size());
std::transform(std::begin(doubles), std::end(doubles), std::begin(floats), [&](const double& value) { return static_cast<float>(value); });
```

Comment: Your problem is this "treat warnings as errors" nonsensical option. Sure, `transform` works, is more explicit, and thus might be preferred in some code bases, but "does not work" for `copy` is clearly wrong.

Comment: @MarcGlisse, true, I'll change that wording. I disagree with the option being "nonsensical" though.

Answer (score 1):

In general case - no.

In specific cases, on a given platform the representation of `float` and `double` might be the same, and the copy will succeed. But it doesn't make any practical sense anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy` is type agnostic (just sees bytes) and can't do type conversion. Just use `std::transform` as @AzP said:

```
std::transform(a, a + 5, b, [](double d) -> float {return float(d);});
```